# Identify an end of democracy quote, possibly by F. Herbert

Tags: story-identification, quotes

I recall that there was a quote about downfall or ending of democracy, either through its own excesses or through overblown bureaucracy, or something similar. I suspect it's from one of F.Herbert's Dune novels, but I am unable to find it.

Anyone know where it's from and how does it go exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be this quote from *Dune*?

> Democracy is susceptible to being led astray by having scapegoats paraded in front of the electorate. Get the rich, the greedy, the criminals, the stupid leader and so on ad nauseam.

Or this one, from *Chapterhouse: Dune*?

> The downfall of democracy is the tyranny of the minority cloaked in the mask of the majority, where it is either overthrown by its own excesses or eaten away by bureaucracy. First, a Civil Service law masked in the lie that it is the only way to correct demagogic excesses and spoils systems. Then the accumulation of power in places the voters could not touch. And finally, aristocracy.

Comment: It's the second one, thank you. I remembered it in a more condensed form, which is probably why I didn't catch it while Googling.